# How to set the limits of integration to find the probability of the distance between two points

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

"Two points are selected randomly on a line of lenght L, so as to be on opposite sides of the midpoint of the line. Find the probability that the distance between the two points is greater than $3L/4$"

This problem is almost like one from *A First Course in Probability Theory* by Sheldon Ross (eight edition, chapter 6 problem 18), but the book asks for the probability that the distance between the two points is greater than $L/3$.

Since X and Y are uniformely distributed over $(0,L/2)$ and $(L/2,L)$

$f_x(x)=2/L=f_y(y)$

and due to independence

$f(x,y)=f_x(x)f_y(y)=4/L^2$

but I don't know how to set the limits of the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an integral, since the distribution is uniform. You're looking at a point $\langle x,y\rangle$ chosen with uniform distribution from the square $[0,L/2]\times[L/2,1]$. The point satisfies $y-x>\frac34L$ if and only if it's above the line segment from $\langle 0,3L/4\rangle$ to $\langle L/4,1\rangle$. What fraction of the area of that square is above that line segment?